# How can I write my script without using public?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

So I'm currently trying to add my player object with it's script into my camera script that is written for camera object.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target;
    private Vector3 offset;
    private float damping = 0.2f;

    public bool canMove = true;
    public PlayerMovement player;

    private void Start()
    {
        player = gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerMovement>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (player.faceRight)
        {

            offset = new Vector3(1f, 0.5f, -10f);
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, target.position, damping) + offset;

        }

        else if (!player.faceRight)
        {

            offset = new Vector3(-1f, 0.5f, -10f);
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, target.position, damping) + offset;

        }
    
    }
}
```

My problem is that I can't write `player = gameObject.Find("Player");` because unity is saying something like "those are different types of elements" but I can drag my player object if I write `public PlayerMovement player;` and it works. The thing is I want to learn how to use that without dragging my object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you **can** expose and assign **`private`** (and `protected`) fields via the Inspector by using the attribute [`[SerializeField]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeField.html) without being forced to make them `public` like e.g.

```c#
[SerializeField] private PlayerMovement player;

private void Awake()
{
    // if it's not referenced via the Inspector
    // get it from this object on runtime as fallback
    if(!player) player = GetComponent<PlayerMovement>();
}
```

And then, well, your field `player` is of type `PlayerMovement` while [`Find`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html) returns a `GameObject` → Not the same type.

Now if you want to get that component from the same object this script is attached to .. then why should you use the expensive `Find` at all?! You already know the object! Use only `GetComponent` to get the component attached tot he same object as this script (just like in the code above).

If you really want to use `Find` then you want to use `GetComponent` on the result, not on [`gameObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component-gameObject.html) which is the reference to that scripts **own** `GameObject`. You would rather do

```c#
[SerializeField] private PlayerMovement player;

private void Awake()
{
    if(!player) player = GameObject.Find("player").GetComponent<PlayerMovement>();
}
```

or if there is anyway only one instance of that type in your scene you can also simply use [`FindObjectOfType`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectOfType.html)

```c#
[SerializeField] private PlayerMovement player;

private void Awake()
{
    if(!player) player = FindObjectOfType<PlayerMovement>();
}
```

---

In general: If you can reference something via the Inspector it is always better doing so. It is way more efficient because the reference will be serialized into your scene or prefab asset so when it is loaded you already "know" the target reference. Using `Find` is very expensive and even though it was optimized a lot in later versions also `GetComponent` is work you could be avoiding ;)

Comment: I really liked what you explain but there is a problem. I'm trying to add script elements of player object's to camera object's script. which means that I have some attributes in player object's script and I want to use them in my camera object's script. so camera and player are two different objects. that's why I used "Find".

Comment: Yes but if you simply reference them via the Inspector you don't need `Find` at all. And if you need it (for example because you spawn the player later into the scene) then go for the second or third code snippet where I told you how to use `Find` correctly in your case